# Is $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}x \,dx$ is equal to $\pi/2$?

Tags: complex-integration

> Is $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}x \,dx$ is equal to $\pi/2$ for positive real $n$?

I've come to this answer by inverse Fourier transform. But since there is n, I am quite confused that I didn't get n in the answer. Is this answer incorrect?
Thank you

Comment: Substitute $y = n\cdot x$. What is the result?

Comment: Oh yes, n is real, and n > 0

Comment: Don't add conditions in the comments, add them to the question. All details should be in the body of the question, not in comments. @NikhanbayevNursultan

Comment: Sorry, I am very beginner here. I will take it into account next time. @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1):

Change of variable:

Let $u=nx$ Then $\frac{du}{u}=\frac{n\,dx}{nx} = \frac{dx}{x}$. So:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{x}\,dx = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u}\,du$$

So this is true for any *positive* $n$. For negative $n$, you get the result:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{x}\,dx = -\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u}\,du$$

Answer (score 1):

Make the change of variables $u = nx$. Then
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{x} dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{(u/n)} d(u/n) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u} du.$$ So indeed, the integral does not depend on $n$ (and your value is correct).